# Failed to send HidOutputReport

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to send output report over hid to device.

```
var device = await HidDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceDescriptor.Id, Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
HidOutputReport outReport = device.CreateOutputReport();
byte[] buffer = new byte[] { 10, 20, 30, 40 };
DataWriter dataWriter = new DataWriter();
dataWriter.WriteBytes(buffer);
outReport.Data = dataWriter.DetachBuffer();
```

But it fails with exception.

```
Message: 
    System.ArgumentException : Value does not fall within the expected range.
  Stack Trace: 
    HidOutputReport.put_Data(IBuffer value)
```

What is wrong with it? Code is copied form sample in docs.

If new buffer Length matches old outReport.Data.Length, then I am getting exception at

```
await device.SendOutputReportAsync(outReport); 

// System.ArgumentException: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'
 StackTrace:
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at MyMethod()
```

I am trying to run this method in xunit test.

Comment: What is { 10, 20, 30, 40 } supposed to mean to the device?  Be careful to not just blindly copy the example code.

Comment: @HansPassant My device accepts everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out first byte in buffer is reportId, and it cannot be random. After setting this first byte to correct Id everything works.

Also buffer.Length has to be exact same capacity as outReport.Data.